# How to list `systemd-analyze blame` chronological records?

Tags: systemd

I need to extract all the records i get by `systemd-analyze blame` in chronological order(it would be better) to build a chart of services bootloading time from very beginning up to date.

Follow example demonstrates an idea of what i'm looking for:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame --very-beginning --up-to-date --all-records
====Today
997ms systemd-rfkill.service
665ms dev-nvme0n1p3.device
604ms systemd-journal-flush.service
424ms networkd-dispatcher.service
326ms udisks2.service
324ms containerd.service
====Yesterday
997ms systemd-rfkill.service
665ms dev-nvme0n1p3.device
604ms systemd-journal-flush.service
424ms networkd-dispatcher.service
326ms udisks2.service
324ms containerd.service
====Day before yesterday
997ms systemd-rfkill.service
665ms dev-nvme0n1p3.device
604ms systemd-journal-flush.service
424ms networkd-dispatcher.service
326ms udisks2.service
324ms containerd.service
...
====Very beginning
```

I know how to parse `journald` logs, but i don't know which type of records i have to search and whether blame-records are there.

Does SystemD use journald records to compute the bootloading time records?
What is an algorithm of such computing?

Comment: Isn't `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg && inkscape plot.svg` already doing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, it's the same thing `systemd-analyze blame` is and gives a graphical representation. My need is to list "blame-reports" for all the saved days to build a chart.